# OrderBy date but containing recors from "half" the day before

Tags: sql, t-sql, date, datetime

```
SELECT cast(Ord.regdate AS date) AS Date,
       COUNT(Ord.Ordernumber) AS [Backlog of line],

  (SELECT CASE
              WHEN CAST(SUM(Ord.Qty) AS INT) IS NULL THEN 0
              ELSE CAST(SUM(Ord.Qty) AS INT)
          END) AS [Backlog of Qty]
FROM Orders [Ord]
WHERE Ord.regdate < CAST(CAST(CAST(DATEADD(DAY,-1,GETDATE()) AS date) AS varchar(10)) + ' 12:00' AS datetime)
GROUP BY cast(Ord.regdate AS date)
ORDER BY cast(Ord.regdate AS date) DESC
```

**Date : Backlog of line : Backlog of Qty**

2015-09-20  : 10  : 50

2015-09-21  : 5  :  25

The problem here is that when we get to next day... the 21 will get more records if the are orders that are done after 12:00 the 2015-09-21...

When we run this it just takes the records that are older then 12:00 the day before and groups them by date.

**My Question is..**
I want the date 2015-09-22 to show and have the records after 12:00 from 2015-09-21 until 12:00 the 2015-09-22... and so an

Comment: Build a view to get 3 columns, `RegDate date, RegDateFrom datetime, RegDateTo datetime` using your half day rule, join to `Orders` on `RegDateFrom` and `RegDateTo` then group by `RegDate`.

Comment: Thanks,
This is a prod server so cant create new view or table without them disaprear in a new versions

If someone els have other fix plz let me know

Comment: Use `CTE` need not to be a physical view

Answer (score 0):

This should works. It shifts regdate by 12 hours first.

```
SELECT Ord.regdate AS Date,
       COUNT(Ord.Ordernumber) AS [Backlog of line],

  (SELECT CASE
              WHEN CAST(SUM(Ord.Qty) AS INT) IS NULL THEN 0
              ELSE CAST(SUM(Ord.Qty) AS INT)
          END) AS [Backlog of Qty]
FROM (
    Select Ordernumber, Qty, CAST(DATEADD(HOUR, 12, regdate) as date) as regdate
    From Orders 
    WHERE regdate < CAST(CAST(CAST(DATEADD(DAY,-1,GETDATE()) AS date) AS varchar(10)) + ' 12:00' AS datetime)
) [Ord]
GROUP BY Ord.regdate
ORDER BY Ord.regdate DESC
```